# Rails 4.0.4, ruby 2.1.0, Ubuntu 12.04 rake db:create fails, postgresql making me sad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku, postgresql-9.1

Using Ubuntu 12.04

I know the problem isn't exactly new, but I googled extensively, check stackoverflow, followed solutions that were suggested to the letter - alas, to no avail.

I have an app in Rails 4.0.4, Ruby 2.1.0, which I would like to deploy to Heroku. I have: installed pg 0.15.1 (tried 0.17.1 as well) gem,
sudo apt-get installed postgresql,
added host: localhost to database.yaml file,
edited /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf and uncommented listen_addresses = 'localhost',

added user 'postgres' password 'blah' to psql database,
tried rake db:create - but failed spectacularly.

Please advise.

```
    FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgresql"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgresql"
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:556:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in `create'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:87:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:183:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `create_current'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"development", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "host"=>"localhost", "user"=>"postgresql", "password"=>"blah"}
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgresql"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgresql"
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:556:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in `create'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:87:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:183:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:86:in `create_current'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"test", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "host"=>"localhost", "user"=>"postgresql", "password"=>"blah"}
```

To create user in psql I used: **sudo -u postgres psql template1** and then inside the psql **alter user** command which I can't find anywhere :(

My database.yaml:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
```

Solved with this database.yaml:

```
development:
  encoding: unicode
  adapter: postgresql
  database: development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: blah


test:
  encoding: unicode
  adapter: postgresql
  database: test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: blah


production:
  encoding: unicode
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: blah
```

Comment: First of all: don't be sad :) Second: can you post your `database.yml`? And which commands did you use to add your user? Can you login with pg console using that user/password combination?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978

Comment: It worked! I attach my current database.yaml for future reference. Thank you MrYoshiji!